# fgets will be ignored probably due to other scanf's

Tags: c, scanf, fgets

The program won't compile `fgets` in the `teste1` function. Or at least it isn't working properly, it won't let me type the string, the program will end right after it prints "Nome do cliente".

If I disable the other `scanf`'s in the function, it will run without any issue.

How do I make fgets to work?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void teste1(){
    char teste[50];
    printf("Nome do cliente\n");
    fgets(teste,50,stdin);
}

void teste2(){
    teste1();
}

void teste3(){

        int opc1,opc2;
        printf("\nSeleccione a área desejada\n1- Clientes\n2- Concessionários\n3- Carros de demonstração\n");
        scanf("%d",&opc1);

        printf("\nSeleccione a área desejada\n1- Inserir\n2- Alterar\n3- Remover\n4- Consultar\n");    
        scanf("%d",&opc2);

    teste2();
}

int main()
{
    teste3();
}
```

Comment: So... what's the question?

Comment: how do I make fgets to work?

Comment: You should be extremely cautious about claiming that the compiler is misbehaving — that most certainly isn't the problem here; your code is making an false assumption about how `scanf()` reads integers.

Answer (score 1):

The <kbd>Enter</kbd> key you pressed for the last `scanf` input will be left in the input buffer as a newline. The `fgets` function will read this newline and think it is finished.

Comment: How do I fix that?

Comment: @xickoh: Several choices.  One is to use `fgets()` to read lines and then `sscanf()` to analyze them — that's probably the best.  An alternative is to gobble the characters up to newline (or EOF) after the `scanf()`, using code like: `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') ;`.  Note that as it stands (in the question), the user could type `3 4 Frederick Handel` all on one line and that would satisfy all your input code.  With `fgets()` plus `sscanf()`, you regain control over what the user enters (or what you do with what the user enters).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler does fgets() read integers? I only intend to read a single integer in that scanf

Comment: @xickoh: No, `fgets()` reads strings; that's why you use `sscanf()` afterwards to analyze the string and convert it to an integer, if that's possible.  You also have the data available to present in an error message: `You typed 'Albuquerque' but that cannot be converted to an integer`, for example.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler can you please provide me an example of a working function doing that? I'm struggling with this since yesterday and I need to finish this project by the end of the day.

Comment: The quickest fix is to add the while loop I showed after the second `scanf()` in the `teste3()` function.  You want a line of input; you make sure you're at the start of a line.  You don't actually do anything with the name you read; you should at least print it.  You should also be checking that the input operations worked: `if (scanf("%d", &opc1) != 1) { …handle error… }` and `if (fgets(teste, sizeof(teste), stdin) == 0) { …handle error… }`.

Comment: That worked, I'm very appreciated.